# Finding and selecting locations in database near 10 km distance from path

Tags: distance, google-maps-api, maps, markers

In the Google Maps API, I have this Javascript. It is finding and showing user the shorter path between two cities.

```
<!--//////   \\\\\\\-->
  <style>
    #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    #map { width: 600px; height: 400px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initMap() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var slovakia = new google.maps.LatLng(48.850033, 21.6500523);  
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: slovakia
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}



function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start_position').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end_position').value;
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
      waypts.push({
          location:checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover:true});
    }
  }

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Časť trasy: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';

      }
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

 </script>
```

And I have simple form to get start and end position. And button to draw a path on the map.:

```
</head>

        <!--////// BODY  \\\\\\\-->

        <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">

<form action="" method="GET">
        <label for="start_position"><span>You travel from: <span class="required"></span></span><input name="start_position" type="text" maxlength="512" id="start_position" class="searchField"/></label>

         <label for="end_position"><span>To: <span class="required"></span></span><input name="end_position" type="text" maxlength="512" id="end_position" class="searchField"/></label>

    </form>

    <input type="submit" value="Show map" onclick="calcRoute();">
    <br><br>

    <div id="map" style="float:left;"></div>
```

It shows a map with selected path (without red circles):

[image]

I need to select atractions for example in area 20 km from path (red circles) from my database. In database every row has latitude, longitude GPS position.

This select I use to get attractions ONLY from city in start and end position. I need all attractions around path in area for example 20 km.:

```
if(!empty($end_position) ||  !empty($start_position)){
       if($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM atractions where City = '$end_position' OR City = '$start_position'"));{
                if($result->num_rows){
                      while ($atraction = $result->fetch_array()){
     ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:left;}
    .tg th{text-align:center; font-size: 12px; padding:0px 5px;border-style:solid; color:#777700 ;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
    .tg td{text-align:center; padding:0px 0px;  border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
    .tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center}
    .tg input{float:center;}
</style>
    <table width = 200 class="tg">
        <tr><th><?php echo "<br> <b>" . $atraction['Name']; ?></th></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo  "<h4>" . $atraction['City']; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo  $atraction['Kategory']; ?></td></tr>

    </table>
    <br><br>



<?php
                    } 
                }$result->free();
            }
        } 
      ?>
```

Comment: Please check here example may that will helps you:
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912796/google-api-v3-show-nearby-markers-on-customer-road)

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/finding-nearest-location-using-latitude-longitude/